# Not able to run my existing spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

Here is my pom.xml file, not able to run the application either in VS Code nor in Eclipse, every time I'm running the project it's giving build error "failed to execute goal  org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE:run"

screenshot of error

[image]

I created my project at https://start.spring.io/
Several errors on the internet are similar but did not solve my problem.

Any help would be usefull

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- <version>2.4.0</version> -->
      <version> 2.3.1.RELEASE </version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.mmm</groupId>
  <artifactId>appenggusermgmt</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>AppEnggUserMgmt</name>
  <description>Application Engineering User Management</description>
  <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.release.version>3.0.0-M1</maven.release.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <github.global.server>github</github.global.server>
    <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
    <!-- <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version> -->
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
  </properties>

  <!-- for autogenerating github tag -->
  <scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/3mcloud/appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</developerConnection>
    <!-- <tag>HEAD</tag> -->
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
  </scm>

  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>${github.global.server}</id>
      <name>appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</name>
      <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/3mcloud/appEngRecommender-User-Mgmt-Docker</url>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven.release.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- <finalName>AppEnggUserMgmt</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- <plugin> Paul - this is a great plugin but damn noisy
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>google_checks.xml</configLocation>
          <consoleOutput>false</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>false</failsOnError>
          <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
          <failOnViolation>false</failOnViolation>
        </configuration>
      </plugin> -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>CLASS</element>
                  <excludes>
                    <!-- <exclude>nothing</exclude> use to exclude in the future -->
                  </excludes>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>LINE</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.release.version}</version>
        <configuration>
        <tagNameFormat>v@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
        <checkModificationExcludes>
        <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
        </checkModificationExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is my class file

```
package com.mmm;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class UserProfileManagementApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserProfileManagementApplication.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserProfileManagementApplication.class, args);
        LOG.info("--Application User Profile Management Started--");
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(UserProfileManagementApplication.class);
    }
}
```